# Porque o Clang não reconhece o header básico (iostream)?

Tags: c++

Linha de comando :

`clang++ "C:\caminho\completo\helloworld.cpp" -o "C:\caminho\completo\helloworld.exe"`

Código :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Ola Mundo" << endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Erro :

```
C:\caminho\completo\helloworld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Já dei uma olhada pela internet e pelo breve que entendi deve-se usar a libc++ do minGW, se for assim, qual propósito de existir o clang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que sei, a Apple criou o CLANG pq o GCC utiliza licensa GPL. A Apple precisava implementar algumas "melhorias" na linguagem para suportar os seus produtos, e se implementassem essas melhorias no GCC, deveriam liberar o código para a comunidade GNU.

Criando o CLANG, eles utilizaram outro tipo licensa, que permitia que a Apple tivesse branchs privados do CLANG e não fosse obrigada a liberar os codigos fonte.

No seu caso, caso vc tenha a necessidade de usar o CLANG, instale a **libstdc++** que tudo vai funcionar.

Comment: a Apple é um grande usuário e contribuidor do clang, mas não me parece que a Apple "criou o clang"

Comment: "Apple chose to develop a new compiler front end from scratch, supporting C, Objective-C and C++.[11] This "clang" project was open-sourced in July 2007.[13]" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) Pode ser q o wikipedia esteja errado...

Comment: usar esse clang é muito complicado, consegui compilar mas so com o minGW instalado e com path. Não existe um compilador c++ que preste nesse mundo

Comment: Existe e se chama GCC brotha. Vc tá desenvolvendo em C++ no Windows e utilizando compiladores open source (pq uma licença do Visual Studio custa uma nota). O problema não é o compilador. Instale o Eclipse CDT, configure o seu compilador e debugger e verá que o seu problema pode ser mais de ambiente de desenvolvimento que o próprio compilador.

Comment: Apesar de uma licença profissional do Visual Studio ser cara, só precisam dela empresas com mais de 250 computadores ou com um redimento anual de mais de 1 milhão de dolares. Acredito que ambos não são o caso do usuário que fez a pergunta. Eu recomendaria para qualquer usuário do Windows a utilização do [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/community/) para desenvolvimento. Na minha opinião, sua utilização e seu processo de configuração são bem mais amigável para quem esta acostumado a utilizar Windows.